# Is there any chance to raise event when TextBox caret changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, caret

I need to call a method when TextBox changes, but `TextBox.Caret` isn't a `DependencyProperty`, and because of that there is no possibilty to bind it. How to know when the caret position changes?

Comment: could you create your own Delegate to handle the event

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to handle `SelectionChanged` event of the `TextBox`.

In XAML you define your text box like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" SelectionChanged="TextBox_SelectionChanged" />
```

Next, you write method handling the cursor change:

```
private void TextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int caretPosition = myTextBox.CaretIndex;

    //put your handling code here...
}
```

It fires on every caret change, so on getting focus, on moving cursor with arrow keys, on changing cursor position with mouse etc.

If you need this behaviour in several text boxes, you can also just create your own clas based on `TextBox` and create your own event in a similar manner.

I've tested this in a WPF project, but it should work in Silverlight project as well.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer is factually correct, please note that `CaretIndex` does not change if, for example, you have a single letter and you select it from left to right: you'd expect the `CaretIndex` to have the value `1`, but you'll find it has the value `0`.